# calling a func from a cog and ensuring a cog loads before the others

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I just got into trying out cogs so I don't know a whole lot about them.

I've got a "running" code for now but it's far from being error free, 
So I was testing with this code, basically I want to be able to call `test5` function via discord `prefix test5` and be able to call it in `cogs/test.py`'s `on_ready`

And I want to ask if there is a better way to ensure `cogs/variables` loads before other cogs

`main.py`

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands



intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)



for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')



@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    #print in the console once it starts
    print(f'The bot has logged in as {bot.user}')
    print('''LOADING COGS:---''')

    # this is a janky solution to load variables first
    import cogs.variables
    await cogs.variables.variables.funcs_variables()



@bot.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    await ctx.send(f'loaded {extension}')

@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    bot.reload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    await ctx.send(f'reloaded {extension}')

@bot.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    await ctx.send(f'unloaded {extension}')



bot.run('TOKEN')
```

`cogs\variables.py`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_bot import bot

class variables(commands.Cog):


    global guild_id
    guild_id = #guild's ID


    @commands.command()
    async def primaries(self):
        print('primaries')
        global guild
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, bot.guilds)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await variables.primaries()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(variables(bot))
```

`cogs\test.py`

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.core import command
from discord_bot import bot
import cogs.variables


class test(commands.Cog):

    @commands.command()
    async def test5():
        print(cogs.variables.guild)

    # this is a crappy solution sense *test5* do show when you call *prefix help*
    # and *test5* can trigger an error if called
    @commands.command()
    async def testfunc(self, ctx):
        await test.test5()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await test.testor()



def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(test(bot))
```

Comment: try to load the cogs in the on_ready event

Comment: i don't get what you mean, do you mean to hard code loading the cogs? i'd prefer not to do that; and if you mean to put the `for` loop in `on_ready` it raises an exception.

Comment: I guess you could have a list, `extensions = ["cogs/test.py"]` and then add the list that `os.listdir` returns, so `extensions.extend(os.listdir("./cogs"))`